# unwanted border around images?

Tags: android, html, css, border

On my samsung galaxy 3 there is an unwanted border around images. You can see an example in the picture [here](http://granthoneymoon.com/Screenshots.png).

You can see the blank images used as separators have a border around them. This border does not show up on the desktop PC or any other broswer. I can work around it, of course, by using an empty div instead of a blank image as the separator, but I need to find why it's doing this because it's being a problem at other times as well.

You can see another example of the issue [here.](http://granthoneymoon.com/screenshot.png) In this case it's the background image which has an unwanted gray border which cuts through the middle of the tabs.

---

Here's the HTML for the first example:

```
<div class="main_title">
    Communication
</div>

<div class="notifications_container">

    <img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/notifications-request-2.png" class="notifications_button2">
    </a>

    <img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer">
    <a href="#">    
        <img src="images/notifications-comments-2.png" class="notifications_button2">
    </a>

    <img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/notifications-messages-2.png" class="notifications_button2">
    </a>

    <img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer">
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.notifications_container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 840px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
@media and (max-width: 799px) {
.notifications_container {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 386px) {
.notifications_container img {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}

.notifications_spacer {
    width: 10% !important;
    height: 5px !important;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 385px) {
.notifications_container img {
    width: 26.66%;
    height: auto;
}

.notifications_spacer {
    width: 5% !important;
    height: 5px !important;
}
}
.notifications_button, .notifications_button2 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.0s;
    transition: all 0.0s;
}
.notifications_button:hover, .notifications_button:active, .notifications_button2:hover, .notifications_button2:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    transform: scale(0.95);
}
.notifications_button2 {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
     <a href="#">    
      <img src="images/notifications-comments-2.png" class="notifications_button2" border="0">
     </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
   border:none !important;
}

// here you can try 

.notifications_container img {
    border:none !important;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: while this code block can answer the question please try to improve your answer by adding relevant explanation with the code. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
.notifications_container > img {
    border:none !important;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}
```